# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to convert json date string into date for storing into SQLite database . After run the application is crash after some time and getting error of  **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error:** at this line Date date = new Date(strActiondate); First 2 to 3 months its run but right now its getting crash.Thanks in advanced !!

Here is my date code

```
Log.e(" strActiondate "," ==========>>>>> "+strActiondate);
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a", Locale.getDefault());
                    Date date = new Date(strActiondate);
                    String newDate = dateFormat.format(date);
                    Log.e(" newDate "," = "+ newDate);
```

Here is my LOG cat error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error:
            at java.util.Date.parseError(Date.java:364)
            at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:560)
            at java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:154)
```

Comment: What is the value of `strActiondate`?

Comment: What is the value for strActiondate ? Also what is the date format that you're trying to convert strActiondate to?

Comment: Sorry for late reply . 12/23/2015 1:28:14 PM this is the value of strActiondate .

Comment: 2015-12-23  1:28:14 PM this is the format I want to convert .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below function to convert one date string format to another date string format.

```
public static String convertDateStringFormat(String dateString, String originalDateFormat, String outputDateFormat){
        String finalDate = null;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(originalDateFormat);
        try {
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputDateFormat);
            finalDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalDate;
}
```

Use:

```
String newDateString = convertDateStringFormat("12/23/2015 1:28:14 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
```

Comment: I'm getting this output   0008-01-06 02:26:25 PM  using your code :- String newDateString = convertDateStringFormat("12/23/2015 1:28:14 PM", "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a", "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");

Comment: Thanks for your update, There was minor mistake, I have updated my answer.. please check it..

Comment: For "12/23/2015 1:28:14 PM" date String, Date format should be "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a".

Comment: if i want only in that format 2016-01-13 , then i used to like this right = String newDateString = convertDateStringFormat("12/23/2015 1:28:14 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: But  this date is store in SQLite database 2015 -12-23 1:28:14 PM and again i want to convert it into  2016-01-13 , So can I use same format ?convertDateStringFormat("12/23/2015 1:28:14 PM", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a", "yyyy-MM-dd");

Comment: Yes you can. As shown in above code,  `convertDateStringFormat`  will take first parameter as original date("2015-12-23 1:28:14 PM"), Second parameter as original date format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a") and Third parameter as result date format("yyyy-MM-dd"), So it will return date string as "2015-12-23";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102197/discussion-between-p-ld-and-dhaval-patel).